# Use i18n in Angular library

Tags: angular, module, internationalization, translation

I achieved to compile my Angular (4) module exporting few components to UMD. Therefore i can publish it to NPM. Only thing I cannot implement is translaton.

I tried to do it in JIT style, but when I import my module, then bootstrap app, attributes i18n are still in DOM (they should not) and the translation does not work.

Any ideas how should I implement Angular i18n in exported UMD module?

Comment: Using ngx-translate or no?